# Marrying Statistical Mechanics and Differential Geometry

Tags: statistical-mechanics, differential-geometry, resource-recommendations

Recently, I have been trying to get a more thorough understanding of the mathematics at the fundaments of theoretical physics. I liked V.I. Arnol'd's introduction to mechanics and the book by Ratiu and Marsden, but what really blew me away were Marian Fecko's book and Ferederic P. Schuller's lectures on the "Geometric Anatomy of Theoretical Physics". Schuller, especially, has this really clear vision of introducing more an more structured mathematical objects, starting with topological manifolds and peaking at Yang-Mills fields/connections on associated fiber bundles.

With that, the mathematical objects that pop up in physics have quite nice definitions and I personally found this way of trying to rigorously define the spaces we work in and objects we work with very refreshing.

Now I would like to expand on this a bit and I was wondering if there is a nice article that just picks off at a description of classical mechanics in terms of phase space as a symplectic manifold (or something along these lines) and slaps a nice coat of $\sigma$-algebra on top and equips the whole thing with a probability measure. Non-rigorously, that's in most StatMech textbooks, but I was wondering if someone knows a nice reference where this is carried out with some clean-cut mathematical definitions and gory technicalities. I'm also ok with a detour via quantum mechanics or QFT, but I'm especially interested in how one can take the phase space geometry and supplement it with probability theory.

Comment: There is a book by Klimontovich from the 80's which I have heard wonderful things about, but it seems near impossible to find an English translation.

Comment: There is the work by J.-M. Souriau; see this [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/102656). (Note, however, that the vast majority of mathematically rigorous work in statistical mechanics is done on a lattice; in particular when investigating phase transitions, only very, very little is known in the continuum.)

Comment: Thank you both for the comments. I gained access to an English version of Klimontovich's book and will start by taking a look there and then see where it takes me.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.00103.pdf) which quickly discusses the basics of statistical mechanics; the main sources for this portion are Souriau's works and the book by George Mackey, on quantum mechanics (this also has a short introduction to classical mechanics on a symplectic manifold and to statistical mechanics... though the font is not the nicest, and I found it a little terse to read at some places)

Comment: @TBissinger Woah, can I ask how you found it?

Comment: @RichardMyers My university happened to have it in the library. I guess that's just look. Pretty nice book :)